# How to determine TLS traffic in snort signature

Tags: tls, snort

I am trying to have a snort signature that can detect encrypted traffic but I am not able to determine the TLS traffic using a snort signature.

The content keyword search in the payload of the packet, I need to search on the header information of the packet but I couldn't find it.

Once I have this signature I will adjust to not match so I can be able to detect unencrypted traffic.

Can anyone can help on that?

Comment: This is difficult to read. What do you want to find in the header?

Comment: Have you read the official documentation? https://www.snort.org/faq/readme-ssl It describes what to look for.

Comment: I guess something like `stream_size:client,=,0; content: "|16 03 03|"` should be able to detect the start of a TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 ClientHello. And similar matches with `|16 03 02|` for TLS 1.1. and `|16 03 01|` for TLS 1.0.

Comment: You can use also for user data | 17 03 01 | for tls 1.0 and | 17 03 03 | and for alarms 15 on the first byte and 14 for cipher exchanges I think

Comment: @Schroeder any keywords that can match the tls nothing specific

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks I might have to test it , but do you have another examples

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Hi Steffen , I tried to test it , it is detecting both encrypted and unencrypted traffic , I am trying to be more specific but I couldn't find solution , please advice ?

Comment: @rekoo: it is unclear what you are really doing, i.e. how your rules look like and against what kind of data you test. Please provide all necessary information (config, pcap) so that one can **easily** reproduce what you are trying.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  this is the signature that I made : alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"All encrypted"; content:!"ssl_version:";sid:100002;),  my IP address is 192.168.1.16 and below are the logs :
01/22-12:54:41.022899  [**] [1:100002:0] All encrypted [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 34.193.227.152:443 -> 192.168.1.16:51884
01/22-12:54:41.022900  [**] [1:100002:0] All encrypted [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 34.193.227.152:443 -> 192.168.1.16:51884
01/22-12:54:41.058415  [**] [1:100002:0] All encrypted [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 107.20.176.69:80 -> 192.168.1.16:51847

Comment: @SteffenUllrich as you can see there's port 443 and 80 so it is detecting both

Comment: @rekoo:  I don't want  to guess what you might be doing. What you provide is neither the config nor the pcap nor is it easily reproducible what you are doing. Please assume that all what I have is a snort binary and you should provide the rest (config, traffic) in the exact way you use it in order to make it reproducible.